# Which part of the CAP theorem does Cassandra sacrifice and why?

Tags: cassandra, partitioning, high-availability, consistency, cap-theorem

There is a [great talk here](https://github.com/strangeloop/StrangeLoop2013/blob/master/slides/sessions/Kingsbury-PartitionsForEveryone.pdf) about simulating partition issues in Cassandra with [Kingsby's Jesper library](https://github.com/aphyr/jepsen).

My question is - with Cassandra are you mainly concerned with the Partitioning part of the CAP theorem, or is Consistency a factor you need to manage as well?

Comment: AP due to eventual consistency.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Cassandra is typically classified as an AP system, meaning that availability and partition tolerance are generally considered to be more important than consistency.  However, real world systems rarely fall neatly into these categories, so it's more helpful to view CAP as a continuum.  Most systems will make some effort to be consistent, available, and partition tolerant, and many (including Cassandra) can be tuned depending on what's most important.  Turning knobs like replication factor and consistency level can have a dramatic impact on C, A, and P.

Even defining what the terms mean can be challenging, as various use cases have different requirements for each.  So rather than classify a system as CP, AP, or whatever, it's more helpful to think in terms of the options it provides for tuning these properties as appropriate for the use case.

[Here's an interesting discussion](http://www.infoq.com/articles/cap-twelve-years-later-how-the-rules-have-changed) on how things have changed in the years since the CAP theorem was first introduced.

Comment: Ancient question, I know, but anyway: nowadays Cassandra can be [tuned](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dmlAboutDataConsistency.html) to be CP as well.

Answer (score 6):

**CAP** stands for **Consistency**, **Availability** and **Partition Tolerance**.
In general, its impossible for a distributed system to guarantee above three at a given point.

Apache Cassandra falls under AP system meaning Cassandra holds true for **Availability** and **Partition Tolerance** but not for **Consistency** but this can further tuned via replication factor(how many copies of data) and consistency level (read and write).

For more info: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly it depends on your Cassandra configuration. Cassandra can at max be **AP** system. But if you configure it to read or write based on Quorum then it **does not remain CAP-available** (available as per definition of the CAP theorem) and is only **P** system.

Just to explain things in more detail CAP theorem means:

1. **C**: (Linearizability or strong consistency) roughly means

> If operation B started after operation A successfully completed, then
>   operation B must see the system in the same state as it was on
>   completion of operation A, or a newer state **(but never older state)**.

2. **A**:

> “every request received by a non-failing [database] node in the system must result in a [non-error] response”. It’s not sufficient for some node to be able to handle the request: any non-failing node needs to be able to handle it. Many so-called “highly available” (i.e. low downtime) systems actually do not meet this definition of availability.

3. **P**

> Partition Tolerance (terribly misnamed) basically means that you’re communicating over an asynchronous network that may delay or drop messages. The internet and all our data centres have this property, so you don’t really have any choice in this matter.

Source: Awesome Martin kleppmann's [work](https://martin.kleppmann.com/2015/05/11/please-stop-calling-databases-cp-or-ap.html)