# Which part of the CAP theorem does the Azure SQL data base sacrifes and why?

Tags: sql, database, azure-sql-database, cap-theorem

It has to be consistent since it is a SQL distribution; it is partition tolerant since it is stored in the cloud and it is highly available. So what exactly does it sacrifice?

Comment: StackOverflow is aimed and answering specific development questions; yours is too broad

Comment: well I thought it was ok since [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205797/which-part-of-the-cap-theorem-does-cassandra-sacrifice-and-why) also got answered ...

Answer (score 6):

Azure SQL DB uses quorum commit based model for intra data center availability. It is based on Azure Service Fabric (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-fabric/). The system is consistent and tolerant of network partitioning but in the case where the quorum of replicas cannot be formed, the database would not be available. Cross data centers SQL DB uses asynchronous replication model and it is available and partition tolerant but may not be consistent in case of cross data center network partition (the geo-secondary database will be behind). For both intra data center and cross data center replication we have continuous monitoring to detect any network partitions or unavailability.